# Nested AngularJS ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

I have an error modal that displays a message if an `$http` post returns a certain status. I now need to be able to add an error code to the display. The customer wants it to be on the same line as the message, but styled differently (small font), so I tried this:

```
<p class="text-center" data-ng-bind-html="message">
   <span data-ng-if="errCode" class="small" data-ng-bind="' code ' + (errCode)"></span>
</p>
```

The data being passed into my template looks like this:

```
{title: "Login Error", message: "Server Response Error", errCode: 106, button: "OK"}
```

What they want is something like this:

## Server Response Error code 106

with the "code 106" being a smaller font (sorry, can't figure out how to change span styles in markdown.) But with the code above, the span is being overwritten by the `message` binding in the outer paragraph tag. How can I use nested `ng-bind` elements? (Concatenating the values before passing them in as a single variable is not an option.)

Comment: your <p> content is html-binded with message. isn't the <span> being replaced?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I figured it out, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use inline elements as siblings to do this. `ng-bind-html` replaces innerHTML

```
<p class="text-center">
   <span  data-ng-bind-html="message"></span>
   <span data-ng-if="errCode" class="small" data-ng-bind="' code ' + (errCode)"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. You posted just as I had figured out my answer. I'm new to angular - can you tell me if there are any advantages or disadvantages to doing it your way vs. the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to not use `ng-bind` for the variables. This works:

```
<p class="text-center">{{message}}<span data-ng-if="errCode" class="small"> code {{errCode}}</span></p>
```

Comment: `{{}}` is not a valid replacement for `ng-bind-html`

Comment: See comment on your post... can you explain why? It works in this case - is there some obvious way you can see it breaking at some point?

Comment: yes .. `{{}}` only works for text ... not html. So either you didn't need `ng-bind-html` because the data is only text or you have to add an element to insert the `ng-bind-html` content into

Comment: Yes, but the variables that are being "bound" are just plain text.

Comment: ok..well then `ng-bind-html` wasn't correct directive then. It was easy to assume you had different types since you used different directives

Comment: I'm editing an existing template; `ng-bind-html` was what was already being used in the paragraph tag. So if I know with 100% certainty that I'm only going to be passing text in, then `{{}}` is OK?

Comment: yes...with one caveat ... before angular first compiles template it's possible to see the uncompiled `{{}}` but there are simple workarounds like `ng-cloak` for that. I always use `{{}}` and docs suggest it also

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.